# Installing opencv for pypyp3

Tags: python, opencv, pypy

I've installed pypy3 on Mac, and would like to use it to speed up a python script to analyse a live video feed.
I've tried to install opencv-python with pip and pip_pypy3, but get the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
  Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/7v/1cg_j6kd34l4k8zgvj782ndc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nymhzjmp/overlay/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 612, in setup
          cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
        File "/private/var/folders/7v/1cg_j6kd34l4k8zgvj782ndc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nymhzjmp/overlay/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
          self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
        File "/private/var/folders/7v/1cg_j6kd34l4k8zgvj782ndc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-nymhzjmp/overlay/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
          ) from err
      
      Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Any idea how I can get around this error?
Thanks!

(The advice from people who have previously had this problem is rather confusing...)

Comment: Bug - https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/657

Answer (score 0):

How did you tried to install opencv?. Try this full path if you are in `Mac`

```
pip install opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```

Answer (score 0):

opencv-python does not release binary wheels for PyPy, so you are on your own to compile it, which is non-trivial. I would recommend [using conda-forge](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2022/11/pypy-and-conda-forge.html) instead since there are many more binary packages available there. If you want, you could ask politely for PyPy wheels on [this issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/195) on the opencv-python issue tracker.

With that, PyPy is unlikely to be faster if much of your code uses opencv. In order to support the CPython C-API, PyPy [needs to emulate C](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2018/09/inside-cpyext-why-emulating-cpython-c-8083064623681286567.html) so each function call is about 4x slower, and of course the JIT cannot look inside compiled C/C++ code. If your code is pure python, PyPy may be able to help, this [sobel filter in python](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2011/07/realtime-image-processing-in-python-6985924592886873374.html) is what got me involved in PyPy over a decade ago.